# Should operations such as landings or approaches be logged when acting as pilot monitoring?

Tags: faa-regulations, logging

When operating aircraft that require two crew members, generally one pilot acts as PF (pilot flying) and the other as PM (pilot monitoring). How should operations such as landings and approaches be logged when acting as PM?

Is there any guidance on this for pilots operating under the FAA?

Comment: I'm assuming that the approach flown is IMC at the FAF.  I'm not saying this is an answer but I don't see the difference between an qualified SIC monitoring an approach and a CFII monitoring an approach.  https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/pol_adjudication/agc200/interpretations/data/interps/2008/ronald%20b.%20levy%20-%20(2008)%20legal%20interpretation.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Pilot Monitoring (PM) or Second In Command(SIC) cannot log the approach. FAA has [answered this in a 1999 letter](http://www.askacfi.com/31880/logging-time-as-pilot-monitoring-when-2-pilots-required.htm):

> You then ask if, for the purposes of maintaining instrument currency, an instrument approach on the above flight flown by the PIC can be logged as an instrument approach by the SIC.  The answer is no.  As the SIC you have not "performed" the approach as contemplated by FAR 61.57(c) because you were not the sole manipulator of the controls during the approach.

Comment: I'm glad they cleared that up with a letter because section 61.57 contains the "sole manipulator" phrase for currency for (a) General experience, (b) night takeoff/landing, (f) Night vision goggles, and the (e)(4) exception for night currency. But it is conspicuously missing from paragraph (c) for instrument experience.